# How to change hotkey that switches keyboard layouts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I use Windows 10. I use the hotkey Windows-Space to switch keyboard layouts (between QWERTY and Colemak). This is a built-in feature of Windows 10.

The Windows-Space hotkey is inconvenient because I often hit it by accident. How  can I change the shortcut to <kbd>left-alt</kbd><kbd>right-alt</kbd>?

Answer (score 2):

Under Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings, in the section 'Switching Input Methods', chose 'Change Language bar Hotkeys'. You will get a little pop-out window which allows you to set combinations to directly get each target keyboard, as well as the general switching key sequence.
For example, I use Left ALT + Shift + 0 for US, Left ALT + Shift + 1 for German, etc.

[image]